# Rails pipeline stylesheets compiling order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I have added a theme. I placed stylesheet for that theme on vendor folder. 
This stylesheet applies some style to body, like font-size and font-family.
Then on application.css I set different font-size and font-family for body.

On development are picked styles from application.css, as expected.

But on production are picked styles from theme stylesheet. Which is not the way it should be.

What could be the reason? I understand application.css is probably on top of theme stylesheet on compiled file, but is there a way to change compiling order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the order of `assets_precompile` by changing the order in manifest file. Therefore, move `*= require_self` to above others and re-run `rake assets:precompile`

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives